# Attribute "xmlns" must be declared for element type "beans"

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I am new to the spring framework. I am trying out a tutorial that uses the spring @Async 
annotation.I am receiving this error **Line 9 in XML document from class path resource [spring.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 109; Attribute "xmlns" must be declared for element type "beans"**.

I want to know why this error is happening and how can it be resolved?

My spring.xml file is below

**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="cs"/>
<bean id="regularService" class="cs.RegularService">

</bean>
<task:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

**

RegularService.java

```
package cs;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import cs.MailUtility;

@Service
public class RegularService {

@Autowired
private MailUtility mailUtility ;

public void registerUser(String userName){

System.out.println(" User registration for  "+userName +" complete");

mailUtility.sendMail(userName);

System.out.println(" Registration Complete. Mail will be send after 5 seconds ");
}

}
```

MailUtility.java

```
package cs;

import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MailUtility {

@Async
public void sendMail(String name){

System.out.println(" I Will be formatting html mail and sending it  ");

try {
Thread.sleep(5000);

} catch (InterruptedException e) {

e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(" Asynchronous method call of send email — Complete ");

}

}
```

TestService.java

```
package cs;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import cs.RegularService;

public class TestService {

public static void main(String args[]){

ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"spring.xml"});

RegularService regService = (RegularService) appContext.getBean("regularService");

regService.registerUser("Skill-Guru");

}

}
```

Answer (score 18):

Remove this line:

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
```

Then you file is valid.

Comment: removing that line removed the above error.Now this particular error has reappeared **org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice**

Comment: you need to add spring aop jar

Comment: And can you please tell me why the doctype had to be removed?

Comment: Why do you think it should be there? You are using Spring 3.x which, as you can see from the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html), does not use a 2.0 DOCTYPE.

Comment: This jar solves the issue **com.springsource.org.aopalliance-1.0.0**

Comment: where add spring.aop.jar

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing the DTD and XSD declarations. Simply remove the line:

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your springmvc `config.xml` has error.

xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/**task**"

Update it to **mvc**

Comment: task is fine here as i am trying to use taskexecutor @Async